# Appropriate aws server for now (picture attached for CPU using rate, etc)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu, ram, network-traffic

I created the website for sending sms, but in some point, the report (success and fail) of sms is very slow.

After that, I tried to check out what is problem in query, but I could not find.

Here's the workflow that I experienced.

1. I sent 200,000 sms, and the report (pending to success or fail) was properly worked. 300 sms per a second report was updated from pending to success or fail
2. After sending about 200,000 sms, the report is messed up, but sending sms worked fine.

The report speed was about 1 sms report updated per a second

So, I checked the statistics of aws how it is working

[image: Performance charts]

Currently, I am using 4 CPU and 16 memory

At some point, the cpu using rate is close to the 100%, and network traffic was very high.

Is it problem with the query that I wrote? or should I increase the cpu, ram, and ssd?

I would love to know increasing cpu is the problem of code (query) or not.

If it is because high traffic of sending sms, CPU, and ram need to be increased or not.

Thank you

Comment: How is the end-user experience? Are they impacted during these spikes? You should optimize for the experience of the users.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein After these spikes, the report of sending sms is remarkably slower (about 100 times) ..

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-trivial quetion.

Looking at the graphs of syetem performance, you can see that there are a few CPU spikes where CPU usage gets quite high, but they are breif spikes.  The overall CPU usage isn't bad, outside of the brief spikes.

So, first, I'd look at the code.  How does it work?  Are there obvious places where the CPU may spike?

Without seeing the code or even knowing what language it's in, there's not much  can do to help,

Comment: Thank you for your comment, after the spikes of CPU, the report of sending sms is remarkably slower than before the spikes. About 100 times slower :(

Comment: Using Java language

Comment: I'm no Java expert, but I have a couple of thoughts.  How do you utilize memory?  Could it be a garbage collection problem?  Second, are you using random number generatioon?  Could be a problem with /dev/random running out of entropy.  Switching to /dev/urandom would solve that.  Again, not a Java guy, so others may have other ideas.